# Adding image to DataGrid row in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, data-binding

i am trying to create a list of users in Silverlight in which i want to show their Image, Name,  Score etc.

I used this code to draw a datagrid so that i looks like a list :

```
     <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="KitchenChart" HorizontalAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding KitchenScore}" Background="Black"
             AlternatingRowBackground="Black" GridLinesVisibility="Horizontal">
                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />                                
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
                                    <TextBlock  Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="White"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Score">
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Black">
                                    <TextBlock Padding="5,0,5,0" Text="{Binding Score}" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            </sdk:DataGrid>

And the i used class to load dynamic data in datagrid using this as :
public class KitchenScoreClass
    {
        public Image Image { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Score { get; set; }
        public KitchenScoreClass(Image Image, string Name, int Score)
        {
            this.Image = Image;
            this.Name = Name;
            this.Score = Score;
        }
    }
```

and then i created a function which loads all the data dynimically

```
private List<KitchenScoreClass> KitchenScore()
        {
            List<KitchenScoreClass> avgg = new List<KitchenScoreClass>();

            avgg.Add(new KitchenScoreClass( ??? ,"kundan",10));
            avgg.Add(new KitchenScoreClass( ??? , "me", 15));
            avgg.Add(new KitchenScoreClass( ??? , "varun", 10));

            return avgg;
        }
```

and at last used this function to add data to datagrid KitchenChart as:

```
 public ScoreCharts()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            KitchenChart.ItemsSource = KitchenScore();
        }
```

But i don't know how should i add images  ? Suppose all my images are stored in a folder **Mysolution/MyImgs** along with my solution folders.
How can i add Images ?

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the image column using "DataGridTempalteColumn." Add a cell template and create an image object to display the image in the cell. For example:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn>

<data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

<DataTemplate>

<Image x:Name="picture" ImageFailed="picture_ImageFailed" Width="200" Height="130" Visibility="Visible"/>

</DataTemplate>

</data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking *how to create the image object*. The XAML looks fine it's the `???` in the code that's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the image from disc and convert it to an `Image` object. You do this with an `ImageSourceConverter`:

```
ImageSourceConverter ISC = new ImageSourceConverter();

var newImage = new Image
    {
        Stretch = Stretch.None,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
    };

newImage.Source = (ImageSource)ISC.ConvertFromString(ImagePath);
```

NOTE: This requires that the image is downloaded to the client machine and is somewhere under the `/ClientBin` folder.

Comment: i have images in a folder... Images along with my solution folders ? How to set ImagePath for that ?

Comment: @CracLock - if the images are in your solution then you need to either a) move them or b) include them as resources. The code will be the same but you won't need an `ImageSourceConverter`.

Comment: hi tried to add an image along with other files in solution and the didi this... newImage.Source = (ImageSource)ISC.ConvertFromString("m.jpg"); But its not showing any image ? any issue of Height/Width value of <Image Source="{Binding Image}" /> ?

Comment: @CracLock - For this to work the image has to be under ClientBin.